# How can I "mount" a virtual drive in Android?

Tags: android, file, filesystems, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I've already asked this question before, but I never got an answer, so I'm trying again.

I'm trying to figure out how to mount a virtual drive into my android file system. By this I mean that I want to make a new folder (that doesn't really exist) appear somewhere in my Android file system tree and have all requests to view the contents of, read data from or write data to that folder (or any of it's supposed children), from all other apps, handled by my custom app.

I assume that to do this I will somehow have to override whatever part of Android handles requests to access files for reading and writing (e.g. FileInputStream and FileOutputStream), test whether the requested file is part of this virtual file tree, and if it is, handle the request, or else, pass it to the default handler.

The trouble is, I don't know what part of Android actually handles these calls. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Stock kernel doesn't provide FUSE (common way to mount virtual disks on Linux) so unfortunately there's no way to do what you want without custom kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can go so deep in unrooted phone. It's kind-a possible with modified kernel: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1306336 . Unless you want to put changes into AOSP and compile it yourself, in which case I can't help you : ( .

Comment: Isn't there some way I can use ContentProvider's openFile(Uri, String) command to check File Access Requests from other apps and divert them as appropriate?